# Helm set env from json string

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have an env value coming from `secretKeyRef` and that is a JSON string. Now I want to parse this string as JSON and select one key of it.

```
- name: CONNECTION_STRING
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: "secret-store"
      key: secretKey
```

The value I am getting from secret-store is:

```
"{\n  \"connectionString\": \"abc.xyz\"\n}"
```

I want to set `CONNECTION_STRING` as `abc.xyz`

Comment: Can you elaborate ? What are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: At first, you are setting `CONNECTION_STRING` to the entire JSON. Now you want the same `CONNECTION_STRING` to have a key's value from the same JSON. Perhaps, consider changing the approach. It seems a bit off.